# Embedding video into view controller

Tags: ios, video

I am trying to add a video to a view controller. I tried using the AVPlayerViewController but i was not able to achieve the result i wanted. I do not want the video to open in a new view controller. Instead i want it to be playing in the background. There will be buttons in the foreground and the user can press it. Here is a picture of how the page is supposed to look like.

[image]

The globe will be rotating and the user can login or sign-up. From what i have researched i understand that it is only possible through using a gif. But how is youtube able to achieve this? Is it possible for me to do so?

Comment: There isnt necessary to play video!!! YOu can have set of images, and use imageview to animate all the images!! Like a gif as u said!

Comment: I am not using gif because i can't get a high quality one

Comment: i dont meant to say to use gif, I meant to use array of images and animate them!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add video first to your main view using Avplayer like following:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Untitled" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];
```

Then u need to create UiView with 2 button as you specify "Login" and "Sign-Up" and make **Uivew BackgroundColor Property:clear color**. and add this code to place view on your main view.

`CGRect  viewframe=self.buttonView.frame;
    viewframe.origin.x=0;
    viewframe.origin.y=0;
    viewframe.size.height=self.view.frame.size.height;
    viewframe.size.width=self.view.frame.size.width;
    self.bnuttonView.frame=viewframe;
    [self.view addSubview:self.buttonView];`

In this way your video will play in background and Login and Sign-up button are working in foreground.